# Google api: cast credentialBuilder to httprequestInitializer

Tags: java, clojure, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to access google analytics data, but keep getting a ClassCastException on my credentialBuilder. Here is my code:

```
(defn credential
  []
  (doto (GoogleCredential$Builder.)
    (.setTransport http-transport)
    (.setJsonFactory json-factory)
    (.setServiceAccountId "X")
    (.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File (File. "X"))
    (.setServiceAccountScopes (AnalyticsReportingScopes/ANALYTICS_READONLY))
    (.build)))

(defn analytics
  []
  (doto (AnalyticsReporting$Builder. http-transport json-factory (credential))
    (.setApplicationName "X")
    (.build)))
```

The exact error I keep getting is :

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder cannot be cast to com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer

I try to follow [Hello Analytics Reporting API V4: Java quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java) example, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doto` returns the object passed as its first argument - in your case it will return instance of `GoogleCredential$Builder` and ignore the result of `(.build)` invocation. You need to change it to return the result of the call to `(.build)` instead:

```
(defn credential
  []
  (->
    (doto (GoogleCredential$Builder.)
      (.setTransport http-transport)
      (.setJsonFactory json-factory)
      (.setServiceAccountId "X")
      (.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File (File. "X"))
      (.setServiceAccountScopes (AnalyticsReportingScopes/ANALYTICS_READONLY)))
    (.build))
```

`doto` is macro-expanded to a form like the following:

```
(doto (StringBuilder.)
  (.append "a")
  (.append "b"))
```

becomes

```
(let [obj (StringBuilder.)]
  (.append obj "a")
  (.append obj "b")
  obj)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why I get the error en how to fix it :)